# Error while XML deserialization to class generated by XSD tool

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, ups

I want to integrate UPS service Locator.

I download from UPS website two XSD templates describing request and response. To generate c# classes I used XSD.exe tool. It generated two files for each template. In both classes are duplicated classes, which make errors, so I remove duplicated classes from one file.

Everything works, I obtain data from UPS API, but when I try to deserialize response to object LocatorResponse (class generated from XSD template) I get errors

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot
>   convert type 'string[]' to 'string' error CS0029: Cannot implicitly
>   convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

My code, I attach also generated class

```
        string authBody = GetAuthString();
        string accessPoint = GetAccessPointPostBody();

        var response = GetResponseString(authBody + accessPoint);

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
        {
            // this line below makes problem
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocatorResponse));
            // this line above makes problem

            var result = (LocatorResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

What I do wrong??

Comment: in which line you get this error ?

Comment: var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocatorResponse));

Comment: Common Error.  The XML produced by the tool usually needs some editing.  You probably need to add [XMLElement("tag name")] to the serialized data class.   The error is occurring on an array string[].  Adding the XMLElement eliminates an extra tag to arrays. Often you will see <MyArray><MyArray>....</MyArray><MyArray>....</MyArray></MyArray? instead of <MyArray>....</MyArray><MyArray>....</MyArray>